# On admin page icons are really big after upgrading from wagtail 2.13.2 to 4.2.2

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

So on the wagtail admin page the icons are really big after upgrading from wagtail 2.13.2 to 4.2.2 [image]

I ran `collectstatic` and cleared the browser cache but that didn't help.